# Debugging iphone application crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

When testing my iPhone application on the actual device after a while the application seems to crash/exit by itself. It does not crash at any particular point but instead crashes after a while of use, for example : i can use the application and then leave it idle. It will crash. How can i debug the problem and what could the cause be?

Comment: Do you use any timers/periodic tasks?

Comment: No, its an application with 7 different views, mostly gathering and displa data. I assume its memory management issues but i am able to determine where the problem is. Is there a way to see where everything goes wrong? (the application is too big to try and go over it myself)

Comment: You may try monitoring your app for memory leaks using Instruments. Does your `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods get called? Are there any messages in the console log?

Comment: i get "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate doesn't respond to receivedItems:'" I believe its because of this line :  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 self.rows = appDelegate.getCourseArray; but i was told i dont need to release this. So i dont really know why iw ould get that

Comment: search your code for `Delegate doesn't respond to receivedItems` and paste the relevant section here.

Comment: I also implemnted an RSS Parser in my application from (which returns the error given above): http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader. Dont understand why its occuring either =/ - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
 if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedItems:)])
        [_delegate receivedItems:items];
    else
    { 
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
     format:@"Delegate doesn't respond to receivedItems:"];
    }
}

Comment: i see. You probably have a line like this somewhere in your code: `Parser *rssParser = [[Parser alloc] init]; [rssParser parseRssFeed:@"http://feeds2.feedburner.com/TheMdnShow" withDelegate:self]; ` You must implement `receivedItems:` method in your delegate, as in _Step 3: Implement the method receivedItems: that will be called by our Parser_

Comment: The receivedItems is included but i have a button that loads the rssfeed. I have the following code behind it, how would i pass the receivedItems factor when creating the view?

 RSSFeed *getrss = [[RSSFeed alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 getrss= UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self presentModalViewController:getrss animated:YES];
 [getrss release];

Comment: where do you call the rssParser?

Comment: I managed to fix it, the parser was fine. The problem was the loading animation (weird but yeh). Thank you for ur help,much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

remove the Break points and disable the breakpoints